# How to catch SQLExceptions during commit?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Using Spring & JPA & Hibernate I use method to persist some entity with Exception handling like this one:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
        public void createUserRole(String role) throws RoleAlreadyExistsException {
            try {
                UserRole userRole = new UserRole(role);
                em.persist(userRole);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RoleAlreadyExistsException();
            }
        }
}
```

My service:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService 
    @Transactional
        public void createUserRole(String role) throws RoleAlreadyExistsException {
            userDao.createUserRole(role);
        }
}
```

later I implement some logic:

```
try{
     userService.createUserRole(role.name());
 }  catch (AuthorityEntityAlreadyExistsException e){}
```

but it doesn't catch exception which report about duplicate key :

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'ROLE_ADMIN' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

**So, wasn't thrown none of my RoleAlreadyExistsException, catch block was missed. Exception was thrown during transaction commit in the end of service method. How to catch that exception ??? Or how to implement this logic in Spring in another way??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) DAOs shouldn't catch exceptions. Let the exception generated by Hibernate or Spring be thrown and leave it alone. Especially if your exception-conversion is extremely broad and loses information (throws away the original stacktrace).

2)  Don't rely on constraint violations to tell you there's a pre-existing entry. You can query for it before telling Hibernate to perform the insert. As long as the query is in the same transaction as the insert, and the isolation level is repeatable-read or better, the query result will be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

EntityManager.persist didn't necessary execute a sql statements : The new entity is registered in a cache, and send to the database when needed.

If your constraints are checked by the database, you'll see an error when this entity is send to the database, in the best case when the transaction commit : it's the behavior you see in your trace.

You can force your JPA implementation to send his cache to the database by invoking EntityManager.flush()

```
public void createUserRole(String role) throws RoleAlreadyExistsException {
   try {
       UserRole userRole = new UserRole(role);
       em.persist(userRole);
       em.flush();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       throw new RoleAlreadyExistsException();
   }
}
```

however, calling flush too much can be a performance lost, you should call it only when necessary. It can maybe be more simple to separate DAO ans service : try cach DataIntegrityException in UserService and don't call flush in the DAO

Comment: if i do exception handling with DataIntegrityViolationException inside service's method, it doesn't work. It only have a sense when i handling outside, during invoking service method. If I something didn't realize, please update your post.

Comment: don't make your UserService transactional if you want to cach exception in this method, or use flush in the DAO

Comment: i don't want resolve it with flush, because it can be not single case. I'm a new in Spring. But how i would service transactions if i didn't make this method transactional. can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

use @transactional annotation for the DAO or service or controller layer for the method you want to roll back when ever SQLexception is caught during commit.

```
i.e   @transactional
public void method(@param somevalue)
{
  // Database saving or updating function
  }
```

if you want specific message to be shown during exception

use the below if you want to have global handler for particular expception class

```
@ExceptionHandler(SQLException.class)      
public String exceptionMessage(){ //return exception message}
```